# GDB DYLD ISSUE: warning: unhandled dyld version (17) gdb

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

Every time I try to run gdb on an executable from a .c file, I get "warning: unhandled dyld version (17) gdb". Anyone know what's going on? (please don't close as duplicate -- the other question similar to this hasn't been answered).

CTRL+C also doesn't do anything. Tried both inside and outside of emacs, no help. Haven't found an answer online, either.

Comment: Can you show the exact commands how you compile the executable, and start gdb?

Comment: It would seem that GDB has not been updated to support this version (17) of dyld: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/solib-darwin.c;h=1f52dd463523a210f11bafd526c7aa7bfb9ce499;hb=HEAD#l69 you could file a GDB bug maybe?  Or downgrade dyld?  Or patch GDB?

Comment: @ssbssa it happens with both 'gdb a.out' and 'sudo gdb a.out'